# Reference variable in class definition

Tags: c++, reference

I am learning C++, and I read that all references must be initialized upon declaration,
and there can be no "uninitialized references". But what if the reference variable is a class member?

```
class test
{
    int &k;
};

int main()
{
    test *abc = new test;
}
```

This program compiles and runs normally (in g++, no warnings). However, `abc->k` is a reference, but what is it initialized to? Or, is it an "uninitialized reference" of some sort, or something else?

Comment: Have you tried with all warnings enabled?

Comment: And would it give a warning if `k` was actually used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The program is ill-formed because it constructs a class that fails to initialize a non-static member entity of reference type.

I believe that gcc should fail to compiler this, but I only received the warning "non-static reference ‘int& test::k’ in class without a constructor".

`test` is a non-POD-struct type as it contains a reference member. (9 [class] / 4)

`new test` default-initializes the dynamically allocated class. (5.3.4 [expr.new] / 15)

To *default-initialize* an object of type `test` means to call the implicitly declared and implicitly defined default constructor. (8.5 [dcl.init] / 5)

The implicitly defined default constructor is equivalent to a default constructor with an empty *mem-initialized-list* and an empty function body. (12.1 [class.ctor] / 7)

Further more:

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the
>   class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with an empty *mem-initializer-list* (12.6.2) and an empty function body. If that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

If an entity is not name in a *mem-initializer-list* and the member is not of class type [with further restrictions] then the entity is not initialized.

> Otherwise, the entity is not initialized. If the entity is of const-qualified type, or **reference type**, [or ...] the program is ill-formed." (12.6.2 [class.base.init] / 4)

Comment: @templatetypedef: An program that calls for _default-initialization_ of an entity of reference type is ill-formed by the paragraph that you quote. I was wrong, though, the reference member is actually left uninitialised but the program is explicitly ill-formed by 12.6.2.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the bug in my previous post.  I've replaced my downvote with an upvote.  I need to learn to read the spec more carefully in the future!

Comment: @templatetypedef: No worries, I was originally wrong too; I was just faster to fix my mistake.

Comment: Interestingly enough (for me, at least), just because `int &k;` is left "uninitialized" (loosely-speaking), doesn't mean it can "become initialized" after `test *abc = new test;`. So, I guess then it's not just "uninitialized", but also *permanently uninitializ-able*!

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually wont compile at all on Visual C++. In general it best to leave as little to chance as possible. You need to initialize refence members using an initialiser list in the constructor:

```
class test
{
public:
 test(int& x) : k(x)
 {
 }
 int& k;
};
```

Comment: I use g++ as provided from MinGW, is this not a good compiler?

Comment: @ManRow: It's not necessarily about G++ or VC++ being good or bad compilers (though people certainly have strong opinions about that). Different compilers tend to implement edge cases differently (see templatetypedef's answer). Understanding how your compiler works is the important part of the battle. In this case, it's probably VC++ that's not strictly standards-compliant.

Comment: @Cody, @ManRow: if VC++ rejects this code, then it is behaving correctly, and G++ is the one being non-compliant. Both compilers are generally speaking pretty good, but as @Cody says, they also both have areas where they fall down.

Comment: A warning is enough of a diagnostic. Despite the UB, there is no problem running the test program, as it is not actually using the invalid reference. We all know that "seems to work" is a common and nasty effect of undefined behavior.

Comment: @jalf: Yes, that's true. I wrote that comment before it was determined that templatetypedef's answer was incorrect. I'd edit it now, but I can't.

Comment: I strongly doubt binding `k` to a parameter that is going to die immediately after the constructor has finished is a good idea :)

Comment: @Bo: But it is my impression that this isn't just UB, it is downright ill-formed.

Comment: @jalf: Right it is ill-formed, sorry, but the compiler can still continue if it feels like (after issuing the diagnostic). If it were UB the compiler would just not be required to detect it. Seeing that the reference is not initialized isn't too hard though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
class test
{
    public:
        test(int x) : k(x)
        {
        }
    int& k;
};
```

I have doubt on the way reference is being initialized. When stack frame for ctr is taken off the stack, the reference will no longer be valid.